# How to deploy node js on public domain

Tags: node.js, web, dns

I have been putting myself together a personal brand website for a class of mine and built it with node, html, and css. It works all fine and dandy on my local host and even my raspberry pi, but I just bought a domain on google domains and want to go public with it. I have been trying tutorials and resources for a couple hours now and I very lost. Can anyone link me and resources, or walk me through what I have to do to get my local host code running on a public domain. Thank you.

Comment: you need a server to connect that domain to. Then you can push your code via FTP or SSH. google has servers you can buy too - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/websites/

Comment: @Dan Yes I understand that and planned on using a raspberry pi to do that. But how do I forward, my local host project to run on that domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The domain is always public, but you need to put sever ip on
2. you must find a hosting service to stay your app work day or night
3. that service must have nodejs
   I reccomend you using heroku